# Calling ruby from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, user-interface, jruby

Is there a way to call a jruby function from javascript, let's say that I need my user interface to be on the browser side.

Note: I'm not using Ruby on Rails

~ Eder Quiñones

Comment: Do you mean browser-hosted Ruby? Or calling Ruby on the server from JavaScript on the browser? (Since you mention a browser.) Or calling compiled JRuby in an applet on the browser? You see how the question is a tad non-specific. :-)

Comment: No, ruby is not hosted on the server.

Comment: Is it possible to write an applet using JRuby? Because that would perfectly match my needs!

Comment: @Eder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423888/how-do-you-create-a-java-applet-using-jruby

Comment: Are you under the assumption that the "java" in "javascript" means you can use JRuby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer

**No.**

Long answer

You can create some server side application and call it through AJAX.

**UPD**

And yes: [How do you create a Java applet using JRuby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423888/how-do-you-create-a-java-applet-using-jruby) :D

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. But you can use AJAX to send a request to ruby code on the back-end. That code can then send data to the front-end in the AJAX response (for example, as JSON).